# How and where can I find the keys for the locked boss rooms?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

I have found boss doors are locked that require the Carpenter's Key, the Millionaire's Key, and the Celestial Key, and maybe there are others. How and where can I find all of these keys, and any others I don't know about?

Comment: I've only found two of the four keys (Warhorse's Key is the fourth) so far and I don't even remember where the second was.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot about that door because it shows up so early. I actually found the Carpenter's Key in my game, but I don't remember where it was either.

Comment: I think Carpenter's Key was along the main path through the game... maybe in the Secret Alchemy Lab?

Comment: I was able to get them all but wasn't really keeping track of them. All I remember really is that the last accessible key was the Millionaire's Key and is found in the last area of the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the keys are late game items, so if you're not past 60-80% castle exploration, these will probably contain spoilers

- Celeste's Key - Hall of Termination

  - When you exit the teleporter room, head straight up and then open a secret room in the ceiling
- Carpenter's Key - Dian Cécht Cathedral

  - At the top of the right-most spire
  - Requires the Invert shard
- Millionaire's Key - Behemoth's Den

  - From the entrance head left, then down, then right.  Near the top of this room is a chest on a ledge that you need Invert or High Jump to reach
- Warhorse's Key - Glacial Tomb

  - From the teleporter, head as far left as you can.  A Gusion Cannon is obscuring the chest in the left-most room.

Comment: For the Millionaire's Key, where is entrance you are referring to?